# Sending alert at certain time using javacript

Tags: javascript

I've success set single time to send alert. But I have problem to set multiple time. How set multiple time to send alert?
Example: I have to send alert at 14:05, 17: 35 and 19:12

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var alarmDate = new Date();
alarmDate.setHours(21);
alarmDate.setMinutes(47);
// set day, month, year, etc.



function setAlarm(){
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if (currentDate.getHours() == alarmDate.getHours() &&
             currentDate.getMinutes() == alarmDate.getMinutes() 
      /* compare other fields at your convenience */ ) {
        alert('Alarm triggered at ' + currentDate);
        // better use something better than alert for that?

    }
}

setInterval(setAlarm,1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead. There is no reason to call a piece of code to cehck what time it is every single second. Just wait until the time when you want to execute something.

```js
// Set your alarm date to whatever you require

var alarmDate = new Date();
alarmDate.setSeconds(alarmDate.getSeconds() + 5);

setAlarm(alarmDate, function(){
  alert('Alarm triggered at ' + new Date());
});

var alarmDate2 = new Date();
alarmDate2.setSeconds(alarmDate2.getSeconds() + 10);

setAlarm(alarmDate2, function(){
  alert('Alarm triggered at ' + new Date());
});

function setAlarm(date, callback){
  // How much time from now until the alarmDate
  var timeUntilAlarm = date - new Date();

  // Wait until the alarm date, then do stuff.
  setTimeout(callback, timeUntilAlarm);
}
```